# Framework Ionic requisição http celular

Tags: android, ionic, http, framework, requisição

Eu tenho uma pagina ionic que faz requisição para uma pagina no codeigniter, eu envio os dados e recebo de forma correta, sem problemas no browser, porém quando eu transformo em .apk e rodo no celular a aplicação até  roda porém qualquer botão que tenha faça uma requisição http não funciona, alguem sabe o porquê?

Comment: Poste como você implementou essas chamadas em um cenário mínimo para facilitar a análise e possivelmente uma resposta.

Comment: Meu codigo em angular js:
$http.get("http://localhost/index.php/HomeController/listando").success(function(data,status){

      $scope.listando = data;
      }).error(function(data,status){
              console.log("error");
eu recebo esses dados e passo para um ng-controller, porém ta funcionando no web browser eu tentei arrumar as configurações no app.js para ele aceitar :

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};

Answer (score 1):

Opa, eu também estou começando, mas acho que essa eu posso te dar uma luz
Quando você coloca a sua aplicação no celular, você não esta mais mandando a sua requisição para o localhost. você precisa conectar o celular e o seu computador com o webservice na mesma rede, e colocar na requisição, onde tem o nome localhost, o ip do seu computador.